# Send PHP array from one form to other in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have two forms.
One reads a file using PHP and returns an array. I then what to send this array as an input to another form for some querying.

How do I go about it? Thanks

So far, I have something like this.

```
 <form  name ="INPUT" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" ">
     <p id="upload_text"><br/>
        <textarea name="queryList" id="queryList" cols="35" rows="10" wrap="physical" value='' onclick ="document.INPUT.queryList.value='';">
        Enter input here...
        </textarea><br/>
     </p>
     <p>
        <input name=INPUTS type=hidden value=$entries[]/>
     </p>
     <p id="upload_button"><br/>
        File:
        <input action="readInput.php" name="uploadedfile" type="file" size="30" onchange='fillTextArea()'/><br/>
     </p>
        <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
     </form>

    <form  name ="SUBMIT_INPUT" action ="viewPDBs.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
        <p id="submit_upload">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name=IDS type=hidden value="<?php urlencode(serialize($entries)); ?>"/>
         </p>
     </form>
```

Comment: What is your purpose here? I'm guessing you are going about things incorrectly. Please explain what you are trying to achieve. You can submit an array using a list of hidden inputs with the name of each one being "entries[]"

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve better, and how it relates to your sample code? I see two forms, which one do you want to submit, and then how should the result be put into the other form?

Comment: @Jacob & Jason: I am not sure if I need the two forms. I found a sample online and was trying to use. What I have to do is, select a file and read it immediately without any click event. It will be read in an array. And the on hitting submit, I have to send the array to a php file for MySQL querying. It would be great if you cud suggest me the best way to go about it. Thanks

Comment: You would need two forms, input type's cannot have an action. You need javascript submitting the first form (using an iframe not ajax because files can't be sent with ajax), php returning the contents, then javascript using the contents.

Comment: How do I handle an array in this case???

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't full know what you want, and I think you are doing something that could be inefficient and also open to security holes, you can do this:

```
<?php foreach($entries as $k => $e) : ?>
<input type="hidden" name="entries[<?php echo $k ?>]" value="<?php echo addslashes($e) ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then once submitted, check the variable $_POST['entries'] and you will find it is an array